# Equal Height constraints between different UIStackView's subviews

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a constraint scenario which works perfectly when built through interface builder but I cannot make it through code. The screen layout is the following:

[image]

A Horizontal `UIStackView` with multiple vertical `UIStackView` inline. Each one of these vertical `UIStackView`'s has multiple `UIView`'s inside it. What I'm trying to achieve is the following: **inline UIView with equal height**

[image]

When creating such constraints through interface builder, it works perfectly:

[image]

But when creating this constraints through code I face the following error:

`'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutDimension:0x600002b9a6c0 "UIView:0x7f9e6f075c30.height"> and <NSLayoutDimension:0x600002b9a700 "UIView:0x7f9e6c423d50.height"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

I've tried creating these constraints using the following ways:

1.

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1,
                                          attribute: .height,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view2,
                                          attribute: .height,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint])
```

2.

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1,
                                          attribute: .height,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: view2,
                                          attribute: .height,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 0)
horizontalStackView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

where `horizontalStackView` is the horizontal stackview that holds all vertical stackviews.

I cannot figure out *where* this constraints were added to work through interface builder to create them through code.

Comment: Have you created the UI elements with code as well?

Comment: @PGDev yes, they were created through code as well

Comment: Add the code then.

Comment: Ok, just a moment while I write it

Comment: Did you tried `horizontalStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true` as well?

Comment: `View.height = View.height`, `View View View`, the problem with your storyboard here is that everything is named `View`! Give these views different labels (names) in the storyboard, and give the constraints different string identifiers, so that you can read your own constraints, and when your error message arrives you can see what constraint(s) cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the above UI using code,

**1.** Create the `UIView's` with relevant `backgroundColors`,

```
    let v1 = UIView()
    v1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1)
    v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v2 = UIView()
    v2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
    v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v3 = UIView()
    v3.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
    v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v4 = UIView()
    v4.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5058823824, green: 0.3372549117, blue: 0.06666667014, alpha: 1)
    v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v5 = UIView()
    v5.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)
    v5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v6 = UIView()
    v6.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1)
    v6.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v7 = UIView()
    v7.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
    v7.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v8 = UIView()
    v8.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
    v8.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let v9 = UIView()
    v9.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.06274510175, green: 0, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
    v9.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**2.** Create the `horizontalStackViews` with the above created `UIViews`. Don't forget to set the **`distribution`** as **`fillEqually`**

```
    let hStack1 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [v1, v2, v3])
    hStack1.axis = .horizontal
    hStack1.distribution = .fillEqually
    hStack1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let hStack2 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [v4, v5, v6])
    hStack2.axis = .horizontal
    hStack2.distribution = .fillEqually
    hStack2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let hStack3 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [v7, v8, v9])
    hStack3.axis = .horizontal
    hStack3.distribution = .fillEqually
    hStack3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**3.** Create the `verticalStackView` using the above created `horizontalStackViews` and set its `distribution` as `fillEqually` as well

```
    let vStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [hStack1, hStack2, hStack3])
    vStack.axis = .vertical
    vStack.distribution = .fillEqually
    vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**4.** Add the `vStack` the `controller's` `view`,

```
    self.view.addSubview(vStack)
```

**5.** Add the below **`constraints`** to the `vStack`,

```
    vStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    vStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on the "because they have no common ancestor" part. The problem is probably related to your views not being added to a same container view.

I don't know how you created your views, but at a certain point you need to do something like `self.addSubview(yourView)`, which would solve your problem.